# Create and Edit ASP.net web forms project on VisulaStudio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, visual-studio-2017

Does Visual Studio 2017 still support creating and editing ASP.NET WebForms projects after the removal of this kind of project from ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Studio 2017 still supports the creation of ASP.NET WebForms projects:

[image: New Projects]

[image: ASP.net web forms]

[image: Edit site master page]